# Need Ctree Faircom connection string for Tosca Automation tool

Tags: tosca, faircom-db-sql, ctree, faircom

We are trying to establish connection between Tosca and ctree faircom database but it fails to establish the connection.

Getting the following error message:

> 'Could not establish a connection using "connection string:
>   DRIVER=CTREE ODBC Driver;
>   UID=admin;PWD=ADMIN;Database=ctreeSQL;Host=local host;Service=6597;

*Ctree version: 10.3.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean you want to connect to this database from within an automated test case?
(as opposed to using it as Tosca's database, which would not be supported)

- When do you get the error message?
- How does your test step look like where you connect to the database?
- Does the connection string work, when you create a ODBC data source
  via Windows?
- Which version of Tosca are you using?

Did you check and follow the [manual](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=11.1.0&url=engines_3.0/database/tbox_database_engine.htm)?

**Update: Looks like your connection string has the words "connection string: " in there? This does not look right.**

Comment: The Ctree connection string which we used in UFT automation tool. The same connection string we used in TOSCA automation tool. The connection string is working fine in UFT and we are able select the data from database but in TOSCA we are getting the error message as invalid string,when checking the connectivity from Tosca to ctree

Comment: Arul,
can you maybe add some screenshots?
Where did you enter the connection string? How?
Also I updated my answer above... looks like your connection string has the words "connection string: " in it which does look a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for using c-treeACE. Here is information that should help you out.

1. Connecting with a DSN-less connection string, the DRIVER argument should be in braces:

   ```
   DRIVER={CTREE ODBC Driver}; UID=admin;PWD=ADMIN;Database=ctreeSQL;Host=local host;Service=6597;
   ```
2. The Driver name "CTREE ODBC Driver" must match the driver name in the windows ODBC management utility (`odbcad32.exe`)
3. There is an extra space in your `HOST=localhost`

Always feel free to check out the c-treeACE Documentation section and the c-treeACE home page for up-to-date information.

http://www.faircom.com/developers/documentation
http://www.faircom.com/products/c-treeace